# вставить php переменную в javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите как вместо (Осталось знаков:) вставить переменную `<?php echo $lng[max_enter]; ?>`

```
function checklength(t){ 
          var ml = $(t).attr('maxlength'); 
          var diff = ml - $(t).val().length; 
          var ad = $(t).nextAll('div:first'); 
          if (diff==ml){ 
            ad.html('&nbsp;').css('color','green'); 
          } 
          else if(diff>10){ 
            ad.html('Осталось знаков: '+diff).css('color','green'); 
          } 
          else{ 
            ad.html('Осталось знаков: '+diff+'!').css('color','red'); 
          } 
        }
```

Comment: `'<?php echo $lng[max_enter]; ?>'` ?

Comment: можно и так: $lng[max_enter];

Comment: Каким это образом вы вставите инфу пхп в скрипт без echo?

Comment: А зачем вы вообще каждый раз вставляете текст "Осталось знаков"? Можно же 1 раз во время рендера страницы написать эту строчку, а потом через JS подставлять цифру. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем файл `variables.php`

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
$js_vars = array(
    'lang' => array(
        'max_enter' => 'Осталось знаков',
    )
);
foreach ($js_vars as $var_name => $data) {
    echo "var {$var_name} = ".json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE).";\n";
}
```

Подключим (до ваших скриптов)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/variables.php"></script>
```

P.S Если используйте роуты, можно изменить расширение `.php` на `.js` (или через `rewrite`)

Получаем результат в JS

```
lang['max_enter']
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно для начала посмотреть где вы это пишите, если эта функция находится в php файле верстки (например), и затем код функции вставляется в страницу `<script></script>`, то в переменную максимума вводимых символов можешь написать `<?=$lng[max_enter];?>`. Ну а если он находится отдельно как `.js` файл, то тут нужно только парсить скрипт, сохранять его например в другой JS с измененными константами (все это печально и ужасно).
Если  на то пошло, можешь просто вынести функцию в html и там подставить максимальное количество символов. + Считать количество знаков на стороне сервера не нужно, это делает твой скрипт, клиентская часть с этим справится.

Comment: javascript в шаблонах / php файлах, да еще и с переменными php - это ад. Не советуйте ничего выносить.

Comment: и я не советую, т.к это не правильно) Ту задачу которую хочет сделать автор, делает клиентская часть, а не серверная

Comment: Если задача заключается в переводах на клиентской стороне, на github немало i18n скриптов: https://github.com/recurser/jquery-i18n , https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js ...

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае нужно создать JS файл переводов, который будет хранить переводы, а в скриптах использовать например js_lang_var['max_enter'], и в зависимости от языка подключать на страницу нужный файл переводов.